# dbt: How Can I Write Source Tables Into Their Own Schema Without Production Schema Prefix?

Tags: dbt

I'm trying to follow Gitlab's folder and dbt structure. Specifically for sources they've got a separate schema for each of their source tables. My production schema is called analytics and my production database is called analytics. When I run this in production dbt will create analytics.analytics_sfdc instead of analytics.sfdc. How can I set this up so that the source tables are written to analytics.sfdc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The schema prefix/suffix setup is default in dbt. You can override it by changing the `generate_schema_name` macro in your project, as outlined [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-custom-schemas/).

This is the code for the default version of the macro:

```
{% macro generate_schema_name(custom_schema_name, node) -%}

    {%- set default_schema = target.schema -%}
    {%- if custom_schema_name is none -%}

        {{ default_schema }}

    {%- else -%}

        {{ default_schema }}_{{ custom_schema_name | trim }}

    {%- endif -%}

{%- endmacro %}`
```

You can see the prefix logic in there. To override it, you simply need to create a new version of the macro in your project.

Assuming your production environment is a target called 'prod', it can be as simple as adding this:

```
{% macro generate_schema_name(custom_schema_name, node) -%}
    {{ generate_schema_name_for_env(custom_schema_name, node) }}
{%- endmacro %}
```

As per the docs, this will behave as follows, which appears to be what you want:

- In prod:

  - If a custom schema is provided, a model's schema name should match the custom schema, rather than being concatenated to the target schema.
    If no custom schema is provided, a model's schema name should match the target schema.
- In other environments (e.g. dev or qa):

  - Build all models in the target schema, as in, ignore custom schema configurations.

Alternatively, you can alter the logic of the first code snippet to do something more custom to your specific setup.

Answer (score 0):

```
    {% macro generate_schema_name(custom_schema_name, node) -%}

    {%- set default_schema = target.schema -%}
    {%- if custom_schema_name is none -%}

        {{ default_schema }}

    {%- else -%}

        {{ custom_schema_name | trim }}

    {%- endif -%}

{%- endmacro %}
```

I use the above as my macros/generate_schema_name.sql to get rid of dbt prefixing your stuff irrespective of the environment